# Matrices whose submatrices have determinant of at must 2

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, integer-programming

Totally Unimodular matrices, for which every square submatrix has a determinant in $\{0,\pm 1\}$, are well-studied due to their usefulness in integer programming. Has there been any study of matrices whose submatrices have determinants in $\{0, \pm 1, \pm 2\}$? Are there any known useful classes of matrices with this property?

Comment: Exercise 2 on [MIT 18.438 Spring 2012 problem set #2](http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/18438S12/ps2.pdf) is an example where such matrices appear, but I'd be surprised if you can say much about them in full generality.